# Sending custom header for auth FAILED and not request in web api

Tags: php, json, curl

I am sending a custom header, like this:

```
//HTTP HEADERS
$date = gmdate("M, d Y H:i:s \G\M\T", time());
$contentType = "Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8";
$xIncommDateTime = substr(substr_replace(date('c'), substr(round(microtime(), 3), 1, 8), 19, 0), 0, -6) . "Z";
$acceptLanguage = "Accept-Language: en-US, en";

$header = array("Date: ".$date, $contentType, $accept, "X-Incomm-DateTime: ".$xIncommDateTime, "Authorization: ".$authorization);
```

And posting in CURL php:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header . strlen($request));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $request);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

My problem is the content-type.... is changing when sent for post, like this: `[content_type] => text/html;charset=UTF-8`, this shows up in:

```
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($info);
echo "</pre>";
```

This is wrong, and make a internal error in my code..... The write header and custom type shows BEFORE the content type ... the result is two content-types and makes a confusion in my REQUEST!!!!

```
  [request_header] => POST /v1/requestActiveCode HTTP/1.1
Host: IP.A.D.R.E.S.S
Date: Jun, 08 2015 22:02:13 GMT
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
```

How i change the content-type sent in code for the right type and finally have a result from my webservice API? thanks in advance